# why when i log a function it just prints the function not the complete Function object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Consider I have a function

```
function xyz() {
    console.log(xyz.say);
}
xyz.prototype.say = "Hello";

xyz();
```

it prints

```
undefined.
```

But when i say

```
function xyz() {
    console.log(xyz.prototype.say);
}
xyz.prototype.say = "Hello";

xyz();
```

it prints

```
"Hello";
```

Why is that so? isn't prototype chain is trying to look for the property in first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing a function's prototype property with the internal prototype of an object.

A function's prototype *property* is used as the prototype of objects which are created by using the function as a constructor. In your example, the prototype of `xyz` is Function.prototype, because it's a function. The prototype *property* of it, however, is an object which you extended with the `say` property.

Here's a quote from the book [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) explaining the difference:

> It is important to note the distinction between the way a prototype is associated with a constructor (through its `prototype` property) and the way objects *have* a prototype (which can be retrieved with `Object.getPrototypeOf`). The actual prototype of a constructor is Function.prototype since constructors are functions. Its `prototype` *property* will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its *own* prototype.